# Evolutionary vs throwaway prototyping

Tags: prototyping

Who is winning in the "Low vs High fidelity prototyping" debate?
Should prototype-zero (P0) be the first version of the final product? Or should be P-0 always a throwaway? What approach is the industry favoring?

Excelent article from wikipedia: [Software prototyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_prototyping)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A prototype should always be a throwaway - a prototype is used to quickly prove a concept and influence the design of the real product.  As such, a lot of things which are important for a real product (a thought-out architecture and design, reliability, security, maintainability, etc.) fall by the wayside.  If you do take these things into account when building your prototype, you're not really building a prototype anymore.

My experience with prototypes where the code directly evolved into an actual product shows that the end-result suffers because of it - the lack of a real architecture resulted in a lot of cobbled-together code that had to be constantly hacked to add new features.  I've even seen a case the original technology chosen for rapid development of the prototype was not the best choice for the actual product, and a complete re-write was necessary for V2.

Comment: +50 if I could.  Too many times prototypes get promoted as production code, which turns into a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I disagree. There are times when you can leverage evolutionary prototyping. You just have to know from the start of prototyping which one you are going to use - it will affect how well you develop them as well as the technology you use. The only problem is when a throwaway prototype is evolved into a release - it was never designed or implemented for that purpose and doing so is just going to cause more problems than its worth.

Comment: "had to be constantly hacked to add new features". +1. I can't think of a more accurate description.

Answer (score 3):

I think we, the pedants, have lost this particular battle -- alleged "prototypes" (which **by definition** should be rewritten from scratch!!!-) are in fact being "evolved" into (often half-baked "betas"), etc.

Even today, I've applauded at the smart attempt by a colleague of mine to recapture the *concept*, even if the term is a lost battle: he's setting up a way for **proofs of concept** small projects to be developed (and, if the concept does get proven, transferred to software engineers for real prototyping, then development).

The idea is that, in our department, we have many people who aren't (and aren't in fact *supposed* to be!-) software developers, but are very smart, computer savvy, and in daily contact with the reality "in the trenches" -- **they** are the ones who are most likely to smell an opportunity for some potential innovation which could have real impact once implemented as a "production-ready" software project. Salespeople, account managers, business analysts, technology managers -- at our company, they all often fit this description.

But they're NOT going to program in C++, hardly at all in Java, maybe in Python but miles away from "productionized" -- indeed they're far more likely to whip up a smart proof of concept in php, javascript, perl, bash, Excel+VBA, and sundry other "quick and dirty" technologies we don't even want to *dream* about productionizing and supporting forevermore!-)

So by calling their prototypes "proofs of concept", we hope to encourage them to embody their daring concepts in concrete form (vague natural-language blabberings and much waving of hands being least useful, and alien to the company's culture anyway;-) and yet sharply indicate that such projects, if promoted to exist among the software engineers' goals and priorities, DO have to be programmed from scratch -- the proof-of-concept serves, at best, as a good draft/sketch spec for what the engineers are aiming for, definitely NOT to be incrementally enriched, but redone from the root up!-).

It's early to say how well this idea works -- ask me in three months, when we evaluate the quarter's endeavors (right now, we're just providing a blueprint for them, hot on the heels of evaluating *last* quarter's department- and company-wise undertakings!-).

Answer (score 2):

Write the prototype, then keep refactoring it until it becomes the product.
The key is to not hesitate to refactor when necessary.

It helps to have few people working on it initially.  With too many people working on something, refactoring becomes more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Response from BUNDALLAH, HAMISI

A prototype typically simulates only a few aspects of the features of the eventual program, and may be completely different from the eventual implementation.
Contrary to what my other colleagues have suggested above, I would NOT advise my boss to opt for the throw away prototype model. I am with Anita on this. Given the two prototype models and the circumstances provided, I would strongly advise the management (my boss) to opt for the evolutionary prototype model. The company being large with all the other variables given such as the complexity of the code, the newness of the programming language to be used, I would not use throw away prototype model. The throw away prototype model becomes the starting point from which users can re-examine their expectations and clarify their requirements. When this has been achieved, the prototype model is 'thrown away', and the system is formally developed based on the identified requirements (Crinnion, 1991). But with this situation, the users may not know all the requirements at once due to the complexity of the factors given in this particular situation. Evolutionary prototyping is the process of developing a computer system by a process of gradual refinement. Each refinement of the system contains a system specification and software development phase. In contrast to both the traditional waterfall approach and incremental prototyping, which required everyone to get everything right the first time this approach allows participants to reflect on lessons learned from the previous cycle(s). It is usual to go through three such cycles of gradual refinement. However there is nothing stopping a process of continual evolution which is often the case in many systems. According to Davis (1992), an evolutionary prototyping acknowledges that we do not understand all the requirements (as we have been told above that the system is complex, the company is large, the code will be complex, and the language is fairly new to the programming team). The main goal when using Evolutionary Prototyping is to build a very robust prototype in a structured manner and constantly refine it. The reason for this is that the Evolutionary prototype, when built, forms the heart of the new system, and the improvements and further requirements will be built. This technique allows the development team to add features, or make changes that couldn't be conceived during the requirements and design phase. For a system to be useful, it must evolve through use in its intended operational environment. A product is never "done;" it is always maturing as the usage environment change. Developers often try to define a system using their most familiar frame of reference--where they are currently (or rather, the current system status). They make assumptions about the way business will be conducted and the technology base on which the business will be implemented. A plan is enacted to develop the capability, and, sooner or later, something resembling the envisioned system is delivered. (SPC, 1997).
Evolutionary Prototypes have an advantage over Throwaway Prototypes in that they are functional systems. Although they may not have all the features the users have planned, they may be used on an interim basis until the final system is delivered.
In Evolutionary Prototyping, developers can focus themselves to develop parts of the system that they understand instead of working on developing a whole system. To minimize risk, the developer does not implement poorly understood features. The partial system is sent to customer sites. As users work with the system, they detect opportunities for new features and give requests for these features to developers. Developers then take these enhancement requests along with their own and use sound configuration-management practices to change the software-requirements specification, update the design, recode and retest. (Bersoff and Davis, 1991).
However, the main problems with evolutionary prototyping are due to poor management: Lack of defined milestones, lack of achievement - always putting off what would be in the present prototype until the next one, lack of proper evaluation, lack of clarity between a prototype and an implemented system, lack of continued commitment from users. This process requires a greater degree of sustained commitment from users for a longer time span than traditionally required. Users must be constantly informed as to what is going on and be completely aware of the expectations of the 'prototypes'.

References

Bersoff, E., Davis, A. (1991). Impacts of Life Cycle Models of Software Configuration Management. Comm. ACM.

Crinnion, J.(1991). Evolutionary Systems Development, a practical guide to the use of prototyping within a structured systems methodology. Plenum Press, New York.

Davis, A. (1992). Operational Prototyping: A new Development Approach. IEEE Software.

Software Productivity Consortium (SPC). (1997). Evolutionary Rapid Development. SPC document SPC-97057-CMC, version 01.00.04.